# ERROR 1064 (42000) How Do I Correct the syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_inv_amounts (W_IN IN NUMBER)
AS
W_CHK NUMBER = 0;
W_SUBT NUMBER = 0;
W_TAX NUMBER = 0;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO W_CK FROM INVOICE WHERE INV_NUMBER = W_IN;
IF W_CK = 1 THEN
SELECT SUM(LINE_TOTAL) INTO W_SUBT FROM LINE
WHERE
LINE.INV_NUMBER = W_IN;
W_TAX =W_SUBT * 0.08;
UPDATE INVOICE
SET INV_SUBTOTAL = W_SUBT,
INV_TAX = W_TAX,
INV_TOTAL =W_SUBT + W_TAX
WHERE INV_NUMBER = W_IN;
END IF;
END; $$
DELIMTER ;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near 'IN NUMBER) AS W_CHK NUMBER = 0; W_SUBT
> NUMBER = 0; W_TAX NUMBER = 0; BEGIN SELEC' at line 1

Comment: IN must be before the parameter name: proc_parameter: [ IN | OUT | INOUT ] param_name type. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got the syntax wrong. Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_inv_amounts (IN W_IN NUMBER)
```

Comment: @jaycarn, that fact that you have a new syntax error indicates that this post answered the question that you posted. You should select it as the correct answer, then, if you can't fix your new issue, post a new question with the details of that error.